# CARTO Airship widget default text

Tags: carto, carto-js, carto-vl, airship

I am testing **CARTO Airship**. I have a query regarding airship widget default text. There are some default text values in all widgets like "There is no data to display" or "NO DATA AVAILABLE". I also need to change those text to my local language. I could not find any attribute keys like "heading", "description" etc. for this in the docs.

Is it possible to change those text values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a non documented property for this.

In the histogram is called **noDataHeaderMessage**

https://github.com/CartoDB/airship/blob/master/packages/components/src/components/as-histogram-widget/as-histogram-widget.tsx#L156

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. @Jochen  iagolast. I was also able to use **noDataBodyMessage** property for widget body message.

Comment: @AkshaySV please mark Iago's answer in order to show the rest of the community that it is the right one! Thanks!

Comment: @jochen Hi, I'm new to this community. Didn't find any option to mark iagolast's answer. Please advise me how to mark his answer.

Comment: @AkshaySV No big deal ;-) simply click on the grey checkmark right beneath the downvote arrow. It will turn green and the answer is 'marked' (we call it 'accepted')

Comment: ... but you should of course know this, since you earned the 'informed' badge for reading the entire tour page!